# WHERE, ORDER BY по алиасам

Tags: alias, sql-server

Привет всем!
Пытаюсь вывести простенькую такую табличку, суть которой - список компаний, и количество сотрудников в этих компаниях. Выводить нужно только те компании, в которых количество сотрудников больше 0.

Запрос:

```
SELECT 
[Name] AS [comName],
[ID] AS [comId],
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CorpDB.dbo.Employees WHERE CompanyRef = Companies.ID) AS staffCount
FROM Companies
WHERE staffCount >0
```

При попытке выполнить этот запрос появляется сообщение:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Недопустимое имя столбца "staffCount".
```

Ругается на staffCount после WHERE.
Как группировать, упорядочивать по таким алиасам?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что ругается именно после WHERE а не после AS ?

Comment: @Alexandr Vasilenko,  по ошибке мышем тыкаю, в редакторе выделяется строка с WHERE staffCount >0.

@cerberus, хочу вывести список компаний с количеством сотрудников в каждой из них. КОмпании с количеством сотрудников 0 выводить не нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
SELECT 
Companies.[Name] AS [comName],
Companies.[ID] AS [comId],
COUNT(*) AS staffCount
FROM Companies
inner join  CorpDB.dbo.Employees on CompanyRef = Companies.ID
group by Companies.[Name], Companies.[ID]
```

inner join означает, что выбраны будут только те компании, в которых есть хотя бы один работник, поэтому условие не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя использовать АЛИАС вычислимого поля в WHERE. У вас оно вычисляемое и пока запрос не выполнен и не подсчитан staff не понятно что в нем лежит.
А также я бы порекомендовал бы от себя использовать аналитические функции для устранения таких вещей как 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CorpDB.dbo.Employees WHERE CompanyRef = Companies.ID)
Почитайте про
COUNT() OVER().

Comment: В конце концов есть HAVING


SELECT 
[C.Name] AS [comName],
[C.ID] AS [comId], COUNT(*) AS stuffCount
FROM Companies C LEFT JOIN Employees E ON 
E.CopmanyRef = C.ID
GROUP BY [C.Name], [C.ID]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0

Answer (score 1):

Не понял что Вы хотите сделать. Вы пишете алиас для таблицы (не для столбца!), а потом делаете условие на этот алиас
Попробуйте

```
select count(*) as stuffCount
```